# Getting values from a vector of object pointers

Tags: c++, vector

I need to write the name, act# balance and address of the object that is stored in the vector, to a file.

I believe I have the program to push the objects into the vectors, but since they are vectors of object pointers I am having problems figure out how to call the object and print all 3 objects out.

Main.cpp

```
vector<Account*> accounts;

accounts.push_back(new Savings(new Person("Bilbo Baggins", "43 Bag End"), 1, 500, 0.075));
accounts.push_back(new Checking(new Person("Wizard Gandalf", "Crystal Palace"), 2, 1000.00, 2.00));
accounts.push_back(new Savings(new Person("Elf Elrond", "Rivendell"), 3, 1200, 0.050));

ofstream outFile;
outFile.open("accounts.txt");

if (outFile.fail())
{
    cout << "\nYour file did not open, the program will now close!\n";
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
else
{
    cout << "\nBINGO!!! It worked.\n\n";
    system("PAUSE");
    cout << "\n";
}

//  New : Using a loop, send messages to each of the three Account objects to write themselves out to the file.

cout << "\nNow we are going to write the information to \"Accounts.txt\" \n\n";
system("PAUSE");

for (int i = 0; i < accounts.size(); i++) {
    accounts[i]->writeAccount(outFile);
}
```

**Account.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "Person.h"

using namespace std;

// Account class - abstract/parent class
class Account
{

private:
    int actNumber;
    double actBallance;
    Person PersonName;
public:
    Account();
    Account(int, double, Person*);
    int getActNumber();
    virtual double getActBallance();
    string getName();
    string getAdd();
    void deposit(double);
    void withdrawl(double);
    virtual void writeAccount(ofstream&);
    virtual void readAccount(ifstream&);

    void testAccount(int i);

};

// Checking class: inherits from the Account class
class Checking : public Account
{

private:
    double monthlyFee;

public:
    Checking();
    Checking(Person*, int, double, double);
    void setMonthlyFee(double);
    double getActBallance();
    void writeAccount(ofstream&);
    void readAccount(ifstream&);

};



// Savings class: inherits from the Account class
class Savings : public Account
{


private:
    int interestRate;

public:
    Savings();
    Savings(Person*, int, double, double); // person, act#, Ballance, Interest Rate
    void setInterestRate(double);
    double getActBallance();
    void writeAccount(ofstream&);
    void readAccount(ifstream&);

};
```

**Account.cpp**

```
#include "Account.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;



Account::Account()
{
    actNumber = 0;
    actBallance = 0.0;

}


Account::Account(int act, double bal, Person* name)
{
    actNumber = act;
    actBallance = bal;
}


int Account::getActNumber() 
{
    return actNumber;
}
double Account::getActBallance() 
{
    return actBallance;
}
string Account::getName()
{
    return PersonName.getName();
}
string Account::getAdd()
{
    return PersonName.getAddress();
}
void Account::deposit(double money) 
{
    actBallance += money;
}
void Account::withdrawl(double money) 
{
    actBallance -= money;
}

void Account::writeAccount(ofstream& output)
{
    output << actNumber << "\n" << actBallance << "\n" << PersonName.getName() << "\n" << PersonName.getAddress() << endl;
}

void Account::readAccount(ifstream& output)
{
    output >> actNumber;
    output >> actBallance;
}


// Checking Account
Checking::Checking() {
    monthlyFee = 0;
}

Checking::Checking(Person* per, int actNum, double bal, double interest) {

    bal -= monthlyFee;

    Account:Account(actNum, bal, per);
}

void Checking::setMonthlyFee(double fee) {
    monthlyFee = fee;
}

double Checking::getActBallance() {
    double ballance = Account::getActBallance();
    return ballance = monthlyFee;

}

void Checking::readAccount(ifstream& output) {

    int actNumber = Account::getActNumber();
    int actBallance = Account::getActBallance() - monthlyFee;

    output >> actNumber;
    output >> actBallance;

}

void Checking::writeAccount(ofstream& output) {

    int actNumber = Account::getActNumber();
    int actBallance = Account::getActBallance();

    output << actNumber << "\n" << actBallance << endl;
}



// Savings Account
Savings::Savings() {
    interestRate = 0;

}
// Savings(Person, int, double, double) // person, act#, Ballance, Interest Rate
Savings::Savings(Person* per, int actNum, double bal, double interest) {

    bal += (bal * interest);

    Account:Account(actNum, bal, per);

}

void Savings::setInterestRate(double rate) {
    interestRate = rate;
}

double Savings::getActBallance() {
    double ballance = Account::getActBallance();
    return ballance + (ballance * interestRate);
}

void Savings::readAccount(ifstream& output) {

    double actBallance = Account::getActBallance();
    int actNumber = Account::getActNumber();
    actBallance += (actBallance * interestRate);

    output >> actNumber;
    output >> actBallance;

}

void Savings::writeAccount(ofstream& output) {
    int actNumber = Account::getActNumber();
    int actBallance = Account::getActBallance();

    output << actNumber << "\n" << actBallance << endl;
}
```

I realize I am so far off... but I have been at this for HOURS and I can not figure out for the life of me, but to take the vector of object pointers and output the objects values.

**Person.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class Person
{
private:
    string name;
    string address;
public:
    Person();
    Person(string a, string b);
    string getName();
    string getAddress();
    void writePerson(ofstream&);
    void readPerson(ifstream&);

};
```

**Person.cpp**

```
#include "Person.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;

Person::Person()
{
    name = "NAME";
    address = "123 STREET";
}


Person::Person(string a, string b)
{
    name = a;
    address = b;
}

string Person::getName()
{
    return name;
}

string Person::getAddress()
{
    return address;
}

void Person::writePerson(ofstream& output)
{
    output << name << " " << address << endl;
}

void Person::readPerson(ifstream& output)
{
    output >> name;
    output >> address;

    Person(name, address);

}
```

Comment: Where are you stuck? Is the program not compiling? Is it crashing at run time? Is it not producing the output you expected?

Comment: I am stuck on how to write the objects to a file. The syntax I used to write just a regular vector of objects seems to be different than a vector of object pointers. Example "Account::getActNumber': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member"

Comment: I now have it printing to the file, but it is just a bunch of 0's

Comment: Could you include the code for person.h ?

Comment: I would recommend starting small. Trim the code to just Account. Figure out how to read and write an Account to a file before you add more code. Work through a tutorial or two.

Comment: @Ramana I have added the person.h and person.cpp file.

Comment: Check if you are closing the file at the end

Comment: @RSahu I would love to, but this is an assignment for a class that requires all 3 classes. This is a project that has been added to more and more and it has just got so unorganized I have no idea whats going on anymore! lol

Comment: @Ramana I did have the ofstream close commented out, I did close the ofstream and it is still just adding 0's for each new line. When I watch the vector pointer it shows the pointer, but for some reason I am not printing it out correctly.

Comment: Before you post to Stack Overflow, you are supposed to extract a minimal example, so your question is off-topic by definition. Note that there are reasons for this (read the documentation!) and that after fixing the immediate issue you can still integrate it into your larger program.

Comment: Do you still see zeroes for balance? What is it printing for name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read again your course books on constructors: there are severe issues in all of your constructors. As a result, you don't initialize the object member variables, and you effectively end up printing lots of zeros and empty strings...

Firstly, for your base-class, you must initialize the person name. You should have written:

```
Account::Account(int act, double bal, Person* name)
: actNumber(act)
, actBallance(bal)
, PersonName(name)
{}
```

Secondly, for your derived classes, the initialisation of the base-class must be done in the initializer-list, not in the body of the ctor. Here is for exemple the correct definition for the Checking's ctor:

```
Checking::Checking(Person* per, int actNum, double bal, double interest)
: Account(actNum, bal, per)
, monthlyFee(-bal)
{}
```

Thirdly, be careful to initialize the member variables with the arguments of the ctor. You sometimes do the opposite and assign the ctor arguments with the (uninitialized) member variables.

BTW, Account is a base-class for a polymorphic hierarchy: thus, the Account destructor *must* be declared virtual.